# LinearLayout - Positioning Views

Tags: android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have this layout.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/numbers_root"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="top"
        >
        <ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/numbersList"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="116dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    tools:layout_height="100dp"
    ></ListView>
        <ExpandableListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/subcategory_expandable"
            >
        </ExpandableListView>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But the problem is that the ExpandableListView is always centered on screen despite `gravity="top"` in the parent Layout. What I want is to have it start exactly where the ListView ends. Any idea what might be causing this?
Should I use a scrollview instead of linearlayout?

Here is a screenshot to clarify:
[image]

I want the expandable listview to appear below the listview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're `paddingBottom="116dp"` on the `ListView` is pushing the `ExpandableListView` down.

Comment: Wow... newbie mistake...Thanks a lot for your answer... and should I wrap the LinearLayout in a scrollview for large lists, or will it work fine as is?

Comment: When I look back at the code I wrote at the beginning of my Android career, it makes me want to run screaming into the night. Wrapping lists in ScrollViews can cause some strange issues, but no, you shouldn't need the ScrollView.